# what data type should select to store song url and name in asp c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload a mp3 and store song details in audio table and save that song to a folder. and  when user click the play button then pass that song url to windows media player to play the song...

i has created a table like:

```
Column             Datatype         Allownulls

s_ID (primary)      int                 no

Songurl            Varchar(MAX)        yes

song name          Varchar(50)         yes
```

i am using MS visual studio 2008 and sql server 2005.

plz suggest me idea and example of code to how to create...
Advace thank you...

Comment: The songurl and songname should both be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to allow non-ASCII characters.

Comment: what is your question, by the way? How to create the table or the program?

Comment: @Matten Why is this a comment, it should be a answer

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna I'm not sure what Rembo wants, the question title suggests he wants to know which datatypes, the last sentence says something about code.

Comment: @Downvoters please delete this question. instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same as you would use when using Ruby and make a command line app, or when you woud make a local windows application - this is so totally unrelated to asp.net that you rather take a good book.

Varchar(x) with x not being max but a sensible length. 256 comes to my mind. Now, song name as varchar(50)  makes no sense either - this is QUITE short. QUITE as in - I am sure there is a song with more than 50 chars. The song name may also be better as nvarhar unicode because you can assume it has not always only english characters but also langauge specific items.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the corresponding C# class per your question? Surely just strings, no?

```
class Song
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Url {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The songurl and songname should both be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (instead of `MAX` 500 chars should be sufficient for both) to allow non-ASCII characters.

As Vamsi Krishna noted, a URL should not be longer than 2000 characters, so thats the upper bound for this field.

The create table statement would be

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
  id INT,
  song_url NVARCHAR(2000),
  song_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

On the C# side, `string` is the right datatype. Maybe `URI` for the song_url as suggested by Firedragon.

Comment: Please check [Maximum length of Url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url), +1 For the answer

Comment: 2000 character (or 2083 to be exact) are a lot more than I've ever seen, but Firefox accepting URLs up to 65000 is hilarious. We use 500 characters in the most cases in our company and have never run into a `string would be truncated` exception.

Comment: yeah! I agree, but i guess the application must be ready for the worst situation, even if it never occurs

Comment: Or the application should handle truncation if it needs to occur - you really don't want to set columns to be massively longer than they typically need to be.

Comment: @Sohnee this depends on the application you develop. If you know how many rows will be inserted and that it is only available to a small circle of users, you'd probably have the columns larger or MAX sizes and don't implement truncation logic. But if it is open to a large amount of users, some fine tuning is necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Uri class that might be what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Makes it easier to manipulate than strings.